# Simple dojo example Error: this.domNode is null

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

Referring to jsFiddle's [code][1] by CSWING, 
why does this indicate "TypeError: this.domNode is null (26 out of range 15) in dojo.js".

Here is my code copied from CSWING, for learning and testing,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    html, body /*standard layout for every dojo webpage*/
  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;/*no scrollbar used*/
  }

#standby {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
   /*
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
   */
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dojo1_8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src="../dojo1_8/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="claro">
<div id="standby">    
<div id="btn" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-props="label:     
Go'"></div>    
</div>

<script>
require(["dojox/widget/Standby","dijit/form/Button",
"dojo/store/Memory",'dijit/form/ComboBox',
"dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(Standby, Button, Memory, on, ComboBox)
{       
    var standby = new Standby
    ({
           id: "standbyObj",
       target: "btn",
        color: "transparent",
       zindex: "auto",
     duration: "1000"
    });
dojo.body().appendChild(standby.domNode);
standby.startup();

on(dojo.byId('btn'), 'click', function() 
{
    standby.show();

  //simulate a request.  hide the timeout in 5 seconds
 setTimeout(function()
{
    standby.hide(); 
    }, 5000);
   });
   });
   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please advise. 
Thanks
clement
      [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/253Te/

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In your fiddle I see rotating coil over button, which hides after 5 sec. I don't see any errors in console.

Comment: What browser/version are you using?

Comment: FireFox 22.0 and FireBug 11.1.4. I copied this code and tried testing out before I amend it. I have yet to amend it. @CraigSwing I am able to view your code in jsFiddle, but not copied code in FireFox.

Comment: What version of Dojo are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my original fiddle, I believe that

```
dojo.byId('btn')
```

should be

```
dijit.byId('btn')
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, then I would set firebug to Break on Errors.  When the error occurs, look at the stack trace to find more information about where the error is coming from and what might be causing it.